# source data should not lost while deleting some data in the copied data using sql. Is it possible?

Tags: php, sql

I have [html button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNzjX.png) in my page. when the button is clicked the copied data of the page will generated. I need to update the one of the value of copied data. If so the original file should not change. Is it possible? to do using sql and php

Comment: what you mean by "copied data of the page" ?

Comment: that will copy the table data

Comment: like cloning the table data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code also you can change column whatever you want

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM table WHERE primarykey = 1;
    UPDATE tmptable_1 SET primarykey = NULL;
    INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

Comment: I have copied the data successfully. In my application i have to print those copied data  in the page.  So now i have 2 certificates having same data but the certificate name and id is different. after copy, need to change the value of copied certificate. so the original certificate having the old values and the copied certificate having the updated value. is it possible

Comment: yes first fetch old name store in variable ex. $certificatename = $certificatename.'(copy)'; now update name in tamtabl_1 
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET certificatename =$certificatename,  primarykey = NULL;